# Android - get request received EOFException

Tags: java, php, android, get

**Code**:

```
    String recipeName = this.recipe.getName().replace(" ", "%20");;
    String recipeIngredients = this.recipe.getIngredients().replace(" ", "%20");;
    String recipeInstructions = this.recipe.getInstructions().replace(" ", "%20");;
    String recipeUserName = this.recipe.getUserName().replace(" ", "%20");;
    int recipeRate = this.recipe.getRate();
    int recipeAmountOfRate = this.recipe.getAmountOfRates();
    String link = "http://***My_Site***/createRecipe.php?recipeName="+recipeName+"&recipeIngredients="+recipeIngredients
            +"&recipeInstructions="+recipeInstructions+"&recipeUserName="+recipeUserName+"&recipeRate="+recipeRate+
            "&recipeAmountOfRate="+recipeAmountOfRate;
    URL url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
    try {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        int ch;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) ch);
        }
        Log.e("Error", sb.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

But i get the error:

> E/Error: java.io.EOFException

Why is that?
in previous requests the request went good.
Doed the URL request too long?

Comment: Add full stacktrace(if there is one).

Comment: @LunarWatcher There isn't

Comment: The reason why you do not have a stacktrace is that you are catching the exception without printing it out `e.toString` only gives what exception it was. If you add logging of the stacktrace as well in your `catch` you should see one.